# SerialDevice.FrimIdAsync returns NULL for some devices only

Tags: c#, serial-port, uwp

I am writing a UWP mobile app that connects to multiple serial ports for data logging. I use the following code within the app to find and connect the serial ports:

```
string deviceId = "";
            foreach (var device in _devices)
            {
                if ((device.Name).Equals(portName))
                {
                    deviceId = device.Id;
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" Serial port ID: " + deviceId);
                }
            }
            _serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceId);

            if (_serialPort != null)
            { //... setup serial port stuff
```

The device I am testing on has one built in serial port - which connects and works fine, and one usb to serial adapter. The adapter connects and works with teraterm, but **SerialDevice.FromIdAsync** always returns null when it searches for the port by ID.
I have the following included in my package.appmanifest:

```
<Capabilities>
  <DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
  <Device Id="any">
    <Function Type="name:serialPort" />
  </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

The Code runs fine on my desktop connecting to the same adapter, but fails on the mobile device.
Is there something I am missing? Is this most likely a driver issue, or is a different method required to connect to USB-to-serial adapters on a mobile device?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you please share more detail about your mobile device such as device model?

Comment: Sure, Its a Mesa 2 by Juniper Systems: [website here](http://www.junipersys.com/Juniper-Systems-Rugged-Handheld-Computers/products/Mesa-2-Rugged-Tablet)

Comment: @DavidLee42 Please check your mobile device setting about USB  connection options.
Some settings may cause the USB adapter to become unrecognizable.